# When I run-ios it run but then stop execution until i cross ❌ the terminal

Tags: react-native, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

ismail@Ismails-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd desktop
ismail@Ismails-MacBook-Pro desktop % cd FocusFlow
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/ismail/desktop/FocusFlow/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): >=2.6.10.
ismail@Ismails-MacBook-Pro FocusFlow % npx react-native start

```
                    ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒
                 ▒▓▓▓▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▒
              ▒▓▓▓▓░░░▒▒▒▒░░░▓▓▓▓▒
             ▓▓▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▓▓
             ▓▓░░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▒░░░▒▒░░░▒▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
             ▓▓▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓
              ▒▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                 ▒▓▓▓▒░░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                    ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒


            Welcome to Metro v0.76.7
          Fast - Scalable - Integrated
```

r - reload the app
d - open developer menu
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android

info Opening the app on iOS...
info Found Xcode workspace "FocusFlow.xcworkspace"
info No booted devices or simulators found. Launching first available simulator...
info Launching iPhone SE (3rd generation) (iOS 17.0)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace FocusFlow.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme FocusFlow -destination id=A3B53EE6-A05D-49D6-8F89-819EFDC7921B")

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace FocusFlow.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme FocusFlow -destination id=A3B53EE6-A05D-49D6-8F89-819EFDC7921B

User defaults from command line:
IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (84 targets)
Target 'FocusFlow' in project 'FocusFlow'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-FocusFlow' in project 'Pods' via file 'Pods_FocusFlow.framework' in build phase 'Link Binary'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework DoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'PromisesObjC' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FBLPromises' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseAppCheckInterop' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAuthInterop' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseAuthInterop' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCore' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseCore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreExtension' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseCoreExtension' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseCoreInternal' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseFirestore' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseFirestore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseStorage' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseStorage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GTMSessionFetcher' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework GTMSessionFetcher' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GoogleUtilities' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework GoogleUtilities' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCMaskedView' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNCMaskedView' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCPushNotificationIOS' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNCPushNotificationIOS' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNDateTimePicker' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNDateTimePicker' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNDeviceInfo' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNDeviceInfo' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBApp' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNFBApp' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNFBAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBFirestore' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNFBFirestore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBStorage' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNFBStorage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNGestureHandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNPermissions' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNPermissions' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNReanimated' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNSVG' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNSVG' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNSketchCanvas' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNSketchCanvas' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNVectorIcons' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNVectorIcons' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core-60309c9c' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework ReactCommon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_Codegen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-NativeModulesApple' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_NativeModulesApple' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_RCTAppDelegate' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-debug' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_debug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-runtimescheduler' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_runtimescheduler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-utils' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_utils' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RecaptchaInterop' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RecaptchaInterop' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'SocketRocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework SocketRocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'abseil' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework absl' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework cxxreact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework fmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework folly' in build sett

When I run command npx react-native run-ios in terminal it start but after sometime the terminal stop not going forward nor back